# Is it possible to modify the display name of the build policy at runtime?

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

When configuring a build policy for a certain branch in TFS / Azure DevOps, it is possible to enter the `Display name`, which obviously defines the way it is displayed on a pull request during evaluation:

[image: Build policy configuration]

I'd like to modify this value at runtime, preferably from the PowerShell build step.

I tried to update the pull request policy status with the REST API, but apparently, the build policy evaluation doesn't originate from the status - at least, there's no corresponding status in the response of the List operation.

It seems that [Evaluations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) is somewhat related to that, but I can only see `read` operations there.

I would appreciate a hint on whether it is possible to modify the display name, and if yes - how. My TFS version is 2018, update 2.

Comment: Did you mean you want to **overwrite** a specific build policy name during  the verification of one pull request ? Why would you like to do this?

Comment: Yes, exactly - overwrite a build policy name! My PowerShell script verifies a number of git-specific things, such as whether a `rebase` is required, or if the PR contains some trailing spaces, or whether commits contain `fixup!` / `squash!` comments , etc. This list of checks might grow in future. I'd like to display something like **3 out of 5 checks failed** instead of the initial display name. I understand I can split the script into a number of build definitions, but that doesn't feel elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649162/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-display-name-of-the-build-policy-at-runtime/57686862#comment102038806_57686862), I ended up with a slightly different approach. In order to gain more visibility of the steps being executed during the process, the script sends pull request statuses back to the pull request, one per each check.

So, basically, each check is structured the following way:

- Define the initial status of the check as `succeeded`
- Perform the check, and update the status to `failed` in case the criteria of the check are not satisfied
- Post the status back to the pull request (REST API call from PowerShell)

For instance, one of the checks in my case is the presence of the `fixup!` and `squash!` commit messages. The following code represents the flow described above:

```PowerShell
$fixupStatus = "succeeded"
"fixup!", "squash!" | Foreach-Object {
    $fixups = git log $sourceCommit $targetCommit --grep="$_" --oneline
    if ($fixups.Count -ne 0) {
        Print-Error("'$_' commits detected!:`n    $([system.String]::Join(`"`n    `", $fixups))")
        $fixupStatus = "failed"
        $exitCode += 1
    }
}
Post-PullRequestStatus -name "git-fixup-status" -description "Git Fixup Check" -state $fixupStatus
```

The code of the `Post-PullRequestStatus` looks like this:

```PowerShell
function Post-PullRequestStatus {
    param (
        [string]$name,
        [string]$description,
        [string]$state,
        [string]$genre = "git-health-check"
    )

    $body = @{
        state       = $state
        description = $description
        context     = @{
            name  = $name
            genre = $genre
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    Send-Request -method "POST" -Body $body | Out-Null
}
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

I outlined more details in [the blog post](https://sklyarenko.net/posts/visualize-git-health-checks-in-pull-request).

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not available to achieve this by following official document at present.

As you have mentioned there is no update method in Evaluations Rest API.

Also go through the [Logging commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) checked if there is something like `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number`  /  `##vso[release.updatereleasename]release name`  used Update build number for current build / Update release name for current release, which could also update policy name during current build. Didn't find that kind of command.

---

However, I have also do a manual test, queue the build for Build validation policy which name `test1` and `test2` in an active pull request.

[image]

During the build running, manually update/change the display name for that policy from `test1` to `zero` in web portal. 
After refresh the pull request page in browser, you will see
[image]
[image]

When the build finished, the display name of policy will also updated.

[image]

So the conclusion : **we are possible to do this**. Some related REST APIs may not been documented. For these  we can use tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or directly press <kbd>F12</kbd> - `network` in Chrome to track them. Hope this helps or give a right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the information! This definitely points out a direction to dig to. When (or if) I make some progress here, I'll get back with the details.

Comment: Hi Yan Shlyarenko, did you get a chance to implement the solution that suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: To be honest, I ended up taking a different route. Instead of updating the build policy name during pull request verification, I modified the PowerShell step to send pull request statuses, one per each check the script does. Thus, I have the normal build policy, which is either failed or succeeded, and a number of statuses underneath, one per each check, showing the exact status of each check. I'm currently testing the solution on a real project. As soon as I'm satisfied with the result, I'll post a separate answer to this thread in order to share the knowledge. Thanks for asking, BTW :-)

Comment: As promised, I described the process I ended up with in my answer. Thanks again for your help!